# sql error when inserting data

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO `properties` (`refnum`, `price`, `town`, `region`, `country`, `src`)
VALUES ('PM33077', '470.000', 'La Valetta', 'Valetta', 'Malta', 'villa1.jpg'), 
       ('PS22188', '220.000','Sax', 'Murcia','Spain', 'villa2.jpg'), 
       ('PS57331', '390.000','Malaga', 'Costa del Sol','Spain', 'villa3.jpg'), 
       ('PI531135', '330.000','Peruggia', 'Umbria','Italy', 'villa4.jpg'), 
       ('PM48079', '770.000','Fort Chambray', 'Gozo','Malta', 'villa5.jpg'), 
       ('PM37501', '840.000','Fort Chambray', 'Gozo','Malta', 'villa6.jpg');
```

Results in error:

> *#1054 - Unknown column 'src' in 'field list'*

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the error message...

Comment: Yes. Don't insert stuff into a column that doesn't exist. What, exactly, do you think the error message was trying to tell you?

Comment: con you share your table structure also? it seems 'src' column is missing there.

Comment: An upvote? Seriously? Why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `properties` table look like?  This error usually would mean that you don't have a column (in this case, `src`) in your `properties` table.

To fix this type of error, make sure the column exists in your table.

Comment: that's what happens when you're studying at 4.15am. Thanks